# why I got error when "push" the element to array list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I wrote the code, but I don't know where the mistake is?

I want to fill out the numberList array from 1 to 6 by for/loop and push.

```
let numberList = [];


for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  numberList[i].push();
}
console.log(numberList);
```

Comment: It's `numberList.push(i);`

Comment: Puhs works differently. you should do the following:

`numberList.push(i);`

check push docs: 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: from where did you get this? `numberList[i].push();`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3):

**Your current syntax is wrong**. The actual [Array.prototyp.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) syntax is like below,

```
push(element0)
push(element0, element1)
push(element0, element1, ... , elementN)
```

**Code:**: If want to fill out the `numberList` array from **1 to 6** by for/loop and push, then start `i` from 1 not 0

```js
let numberList = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  numberList.push(i);
}
console.log(numberList);
```